# Extracting data from multiple variable sized arrays in bash onto one line

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I am writing a small bash script that will find the MX records of any given domain, then print out the hostname, IP address, and reverse address for the IP address. I was able to successfully store each hostname, ip, and reverse address into 3 arrays:

```
$MXHOSTS[@]
$MXIPS[@]
$MXRHOST[@]
```

Each contains the same number of values, and depend on how many MX records a domain has. What I want to then do, is print out a line with data from all three arrays, for the number of values in the arrays.

How would I be able to either a. create a new array that condenses 3 arrays into 1 with this data or b. print out the data from all three arrays using echo?

Examples:

```
$MXHOSTS[0] = aspmx.l.google.com.
$MXIPS[0] = 74.125.129.27
$MXRHOST[0] = ia-in-f27.1e100.net.
```

From that, I'd like to then print out this:

aspmx.l.google.com. :: 74.125.129.27 :: ia-in-f27.1e100.net.

for each MX record, so it would run like this:

```
[~/scripts]# ./whomails google.com
aspmx.l.google.com. :: 74.125.129.27 :: ia-in-f27.1e100.net.
alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. :: 74.125.129.27 :: qe-in-f27.1e100.net.
```

etc..

So far I've tried a few different methods, mostly using for loops, but if the domain has multiple MX records it will print out all possible combinations. With only one MX, it works fine.

Currently I am using the following, but this is what gives me all possible combinations:

```
for hosts in "${MXHOSTS[@]}"; do
    for ips in "${MXIPS[@]}"; do
        for rhosts in "${MXRHOSTS[@]}"; do
            echo "$hosts :: $ips :: $rhosts"
        done
    done
done
```

How do I get it to print just the corresponding array value, like [1-n] instead of [@]*[@]*[@]?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got what you want, but if all the arrays have the same **size**, you may simply index them with an integer:

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#array1[@]}; ++i )); do
    ${array1[$i]}
    ${array2[$i]}
    ...
    ${arrayn[$i]}
done
```

Comment: Thank you, that got me a lot closer to working it out. Now it does print only what I need as far as the data itself goes, but then it adds 12 lines that echo ":: ::" or blank if I change the loop's echo to get rid of the :: parts.

`for (( hosts = 0; hosts < ${#MXIPS}; ++hosts )); do
        echo "${MXHOSTS[$hosts]} ${MXIPS[$hosts]} ${MXRHOSTS[$hosts]}"
done
`

Comment: This could be because the syntax for substituting the number of array elements is "${#array1[@]}", *not* "${#array1}". The latter would substitute the number of characters of the first element.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Rubens and @spbnick for helping me solve this.